# Push Array into another Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to push this:

```
"serialNumber" => $serial,
```

Inside product array of $postArray and

```
"note" => array(
                    "text" => $note
                ),
```

before reservationDate Inside $postArray.

```
$postArray = array(
                "reservationDate" => $timeData,
                "emailLanguageCode" => "it_it",
                "shipToCode" => $_POST['ship'],
                "customer" => array(
                    "firstName" => $_POST['firstName'],
                    "lastName" => $_POST['lastName'],
                    "emailId" => $_POST['emailId'],
                    "phoneNumber" => $_POST['phoneNumber'],
                    "address" => array(
                        "addressLine1" => $_POST['addressLine1'],
                        "city" => $_POST['city'],
                        "state" => $_POST['state'],
                        "country" => $_POST['country'],
                        "postalCode" => $_POST['postalCode']
                    )
                ),
                "product" => array(
                    "productCode" => $_POST['productCode'],
                    "issueReported" => $_POST['issueReported']
                )
            );
```

And result that I would like:

```
$postArray = array(
                "note" => array(
                    "text" => $note
                ),
                "reservationDate" => $timeData,
                "emailLanguageCode" => "it_it",
                "shipToCode" => $_POST['ship'],
                "customer" => array(
                    "firstName" => $_POST['firstName'],
                    "lastName" => $_POST['lastName'],
                    "emailId" => $_POST['emailId'],
                    "phoneNumber" => $_POST['phoneNumber'],
                    "address" => array(
                        "addressLine1" => $_POST['addressLine1'],
                        "city" => $_POST['city'],
                        "state" => $_POST['state'],
                        "country" => $_POST['country'],
                        "postalCode" => $_POST['postalCode']
                    )
                ),
                "product" => array(
                    "serialNumber" => $serial,
                    "productCode" => $_POST['productCode'],
                    "issueReported" => $_POST['issueReported']
                )
            );
```

I tried this:

```
array_push($postArray["product"][],$numeroSerie);
```

Please help.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/array_unshift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply do this

```
$postArray['product']['serialNumber'] = $serial;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make First Array that which array you want in product array after use array_merge

```
$postArray1 = array(
                "note" => array(
                    "text" =>15
                ));



$postArray = array(
                "reservationDate" =>1,
                "emailLanguageCode" => 2,
                "shipToCode" => 3,
                "customer" => array(
                    "firstName" => 4,
                    "lastName" => 5,
                    "emailId" => 6,
                    "phoneNumber" => 7,
                    "address" => array(
                        "addressLine1" => 8,
                        "city" =>9,
                        "state" => 10,
                        "country" => 11,
                        "postalCode" => 12
                    )
                ),
                "product" => array(
                    "productCode" => 13,
                    "issueReported" => 14
                )
            );


array_merge($postArray1,$postArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

These two lines,

```
$postArray['product'] =  $serial + $postArray['product'];
$postArray = $numeroSerie + $postArray ;
```

And that's it,

`+` operator gives union of both array and offcourse will satisfy your requirement.

Give it a try, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

very simple, add this two line code :

```
// insert "serialNumber" into "product" array
$postArray['product']['serialNumber'] = $serial;

// insert "note" into begining array element
$postArray = array('note'=>array("text" => $note))+$postArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will Try this i think its working fine.

```
$data=array("note" => array("text" => $note));
$postArray=  array_merge($data,$postArray);
$postArray["product"]=array_merge(array("serialNumber"=> $serial),$postArray["product"]);
```